# local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-eloquent, chave-estrangeira

Caros,

Podem me ajudar com este erro:

```
local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`clima`.`tbl_consenso`, CONSTRAINT `tbl_consenso_opcao_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`opcao_id`) REFERENCES `opcoes` (`id`))
```

Consequentemente ele me retorna o erro `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` na view.

Já verifiquei todas os relacionamentos de foreign key.

Trecho controller Store

```
<?php
public function store( Request $request, Pesquisa $pesquisa )
{
    $this->guardaAvaliacao( $pesquisa );

    $opcoes = $request->input( 'pergunta', [] );

    $opcoes = Opcao::findMany( $opcoes );
    $pesquisa->load( 'consensos' );

    collect( $request->input( 'pergunta', [] ) )
        ->each( function ( $opcaoId, $perguntaId ) use ( $request, $pesquisa, $opcoes ) {
            $opcaoId    = intval( $opcaoId );
            $perguntaId = intval( $perguntaId );

            $opcao    = $opcoes->whereStrict( 'id', $opcaoId )->first();
            $consenso = $pesquisa->consensos->whereStrict( 'pergunta_id', $perguntaId )->first();


            Consenso::forceCreate( [
                'user_id'                      => $request->authUser()->id,
                'matricula'                    => $pesquisa->matricula,
                'pesquisa_id'                  => $pesquisa->id,
                'pergunta_id'                  => $perguntaId,
                'opcao_id'                     => $opcao->id,
                'lookup_regime_contratacao_id' => $pesquisa->lookup_regime_contratacao_id,
                'lookup_area_atuacao_id'       => $pesquisa->lookup_area_atuacao_id,
                'lookup_cargo_id'              => $pesquisa->lookup_cargo_id,
                'lookup_gestor_id'             => $pesquisa->lookup_gestor_id,
                'lookup_tempo_empresa_id'      => $pesquisa->lookup_tempo_empresa_id,
                'lookup_sexo_id'               => $pesquisa->lookup_sexo_id,
                'lookup_escolaridade_id'       => $pesquisa->lookup_escolaridade_id,
                'nota_original'                => $consenso->nota_original,
                'nota_supervisor'              => $consenso->nota_supervisor,
                'nota_consenso'                => $opcao->nota,
                'conteudo'                     => $opcao->descricao,
            ] );
        } );

    flash_success( 'Salva com sucesso' );

    return redirect()->route( 'clima.consenso.index' );
}

protected function guardaAvaliacao( Pesquisa $pesquisa )
{
    $jaFeito = Consenso::where( 'pesquisa_id', $pesquisa->id )->count() > 0;

    if ($jaFeito) {
        throw new UnauthorizedException( 'Pesquisa ja avalida' );
    }
}
```

Model.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Clima;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Presenters\Presentable;
// use App\Models\Model;
use App\Models\ACL\User;


class Consenso extends Model
{
    use Presentable;

    protected $connection = 'clima';
    protected $table = 'tbl_consenso';

    protected $casts = [
        'id' => 'integer',
        'user_id' => 'integer',
        'matricula' => 'integer',
        'pesquisa_id' => 'integer',
        'pergunta_id' => 'integer',
        'opcao_id' => 'integer',
        'lookup_regime_contratacao_id' => 'integer',
        'lookup_area_atuacao_id' => 'integer',
        'lookup_cargo_id' => 'integer',
        'lookup_gestor_id' => 'integer',
        'lookup_tempo_empresa_id' => 'integer',
        'lookup_sexo_id' => 'integer',
        'lookup_escolaridade_id' => 'integer',
        'nota_original' => 'integer',
        'nota_supervisor' => 'integer',
        'nota_consenso' => 'integer',
        'conteudo' => 'string',
    ];

    //Relacionamentos
    public function setConteudoAttribute( $value )
    {
        $this->attributes[ 'conteudo' ] = value_or_null( $value );
    }

    public function pergunta()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo( Pergunta::class, 'pergunta_id', 'id' );
    }

    public function pesquisa()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo( Pesquisa::class, 'pesquisa_id', 'id' );
    }

    public function opcao()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo( Opcao::class, 'opcao_id', 'id' );
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id', 'id');
    }

    public function regimeContratacao()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(LookupRegimeContratacao::class, 'lookup_regime_contratacao_id', 'id');
    }

    public function avaliacaosups()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(AvSupervisor::class, 'pesquisa_id', 'pesquisa_id');
    }

    public function scopeOrdered(Builder $builder)
    {
        $builder->orderBy('created_at');
        return $builder;
    }

    public static function avaliacao(Pesquisa $pesquisa)
    {
        return self::whereNotIn('id', function ($query) use ($pesquisa) {
            $query->selectRaw('tbl_resposta_super.pergunta_id')
                ->from('tbl_resposta_super')
                ->join('tbl_respostas', 'tbl_resposta_super.pesquisa_id', '=', 'tbl_respostas.pesquisa_id')
                ->whereRaw('tbl_resposta_super.pesquisa_id=' . $pesquisa->id);
        })->ordered()->first();
    }
}
```

Migration.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateConsensoTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::connection( 'clima' )->create('tbl_consenso', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->increments( 'id' );
        $table->unsignedInteger( 'user_id' );
        $table->unsignedInteger( 'matricula' );        
        $table->unsignedInteger( 'pesquisa_id' );
        $table->unsignedInteger( 'pergunta_id' );
        $table->unsignedInteger( 'opcao_id' );
        $table->unsignedInteger( 'lookup_regime_contratacao_id' );
        $table->unsignedInteger( 'lookup_area_atuacao_id' );
        $table->unsignedInteger( 'lookup_cargo_id' );
        $table->unsignedInteger( 'lookup_gestor_id' );
        $table->unsignedInteger( 'lookup_tempo_empresa_id' );
        $table->unsignedInteger( 'lookup_sexo_id' );
        $table->unsignedInteger( 'lookup_escolaridade_id' );
        $table->unsignedInteger('nota_original' );
        $table->unsignedInteger('nota_supervisor' );
        $table->unsignedInteger('nota_consenso' );
        $table->text( 'conteudo' )->nullable()->default( null );
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->unique( [ 'pesquisa_id', 'pergunta_id', 'opcao_id' ] );
        $table->foreign( 'pesquisa_id' )->references( 'id' )->on( 'pesquisas' );
        $table->foreign( 'pergunta_id' )->references( 'id' )->on( 'perguntas' );
        $table->foreign( 'opcao_id' )->references( 'id' )->on( 'opcoes' );
        $table->foreign( 'lookup_regime_contratacao_id' )->references( 'id' )->on( 'lookup_regimes_contratacao' );
        $table->foreign( 'lookup_area_atuacao_id' )->references( 'id' )->on( 'lookup_areas_atuacao' );
        $table->foreign( 'lookup_cargo_id' )->references( 'id' )->on( 'lookup_cargos' );
        $table->foreign( 'lookup_gestor_id' )->references( 'id' )->on( 'lookup_gestores' );
        $table->foreign( 'lookup_tempo_empresa_id' )->references( 'id' )->on( 'lookup_tempos_empresa' );
        $table->foreign( 'lookup_sexo_id' )->references( 'id' )->on( 'lookup_sexos' );
        $table->foreign( 'lookup_escolaridade_id' )->references( 'id' )->on( 'lookup_escolaridades' );

        } );
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('tbl_consenso');
    }
}
```

Rota.

```
/** @var \Illuminate\Routing\Router $router */

$router->group( [ 'prefix' => 'avaliacao', 'namespace' => 'Clima', 'as' => 'clima.' ],
    function ( $router ) {
        /** @var \Illuminate\Routing\Router $router */

        $router->get( '/', [ 'uses' => 'ClimaController@redireciona', 'as' => 'redireciona' ] );

        $router->get( 'inicio', [ 'uses' => 'ClimaController@inicio', 'as' => 'inicio' ] );
        $router->get( 'obrigado', [ 'uses' => 'ClimaController@obrigado', 'as' => 'obrigado' ] );

        $router->get( 'sobre-voce', [ 'uses' => 'ClimaController@sobre', 'as' => 'sobre' ] );
        $router->post( 'sobre-voce', [ 'uses' => 'ClimaController@cria', 'as' => 'cria' ] );

        $router->get( 'pergunta', [ 'uses' => 'ClimaController@pergunta', 'as' => 'pergunta' ] );
        $router->post( 'pergunta/{id}', [ 'uses' => 'ClimaController@salva', 'as' => 'salva' ] );

        //Grupo Supervisor
        $router->group( [ 'prefix' => 'supervisor', 'as' => 'supervisor.' ],
            function ( $router ) {
                /** @var \Illuminate\Routing\Router $router */
                $router->get( '/', [ 'uses' => 'SupervisorController@index', 'as' => 'index' ] );

                $router->get( '/pesquisa/{clima_pesquisa}', [
                    'uses' => 'SupervisorController@show',
                    'as'   => 'show'
                ] );
                $router->post( '/pesquisa/{clima_pesquisa}', [
                    'uses' => 'SupervisorController@store',
                    'as'   => 'store'
                ] );
            }
        );
        //Grupo consenso
        $router->group( [ 'prefix' => 'consenso', 'as' => 'consenso.' ],
            function ( $router ) {
                /** @var \Illuminate\Routing\Router $router */
                $router->get( '/', [ 'uses' => 'ConsensoController@index', 'as' => 'index' ] );

                $router->get( '/pesquisa/{clima_pesquisa}', [
                    'uses' => 'ConsensoController@show',
                    'as'   => 'show'
                ] );
                $router->post( '/pesquisa/{clima_pesquisa}', [
                    'uses' => 'ConsensoController@store',
                    'as'   => 'store'
                ] );
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Comment: tente alterar na migration a foreign q está dando erro para: $table->foreign('campo')->references('id')->on('tabela')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade')

Comment: Desculpa a falta de informação, adicionei o erro completo.